# How can I differentiate between a strongly-defined object and a loose one?

Tags: typescript

```
type Strong = { cats: boolean }
type Loose = {[key: string]: any}
```

With these two types above I'd like to extend in different ways.
I'm curious if there's a way to conditionally extend them and differentiate the types.

Here's and example:

```
type DoTheThing<T> =
  T extends {[key: string]: any} ? string[] :
    T extends object ? {
      [K in keyof T]: undefined extends T[K] ? string | undefined : string
    } : never
```

I'd like it so that:

```
DoTheThing<Strong> // { cats: string }
DoTheThing<Loose> // string[]
```

Is it possible to differentiate these two types within `DoTheThing`? Is so, how?

### Direction

This sort of gets me closer but I don't know how to unwrap this / wrap it properly.

You can check if `string extends K` which will check if the key is defined, if not I'm trying to resolve the type outside of this key / value mapping, and I'm not sure how to do that.

```
type DoTheThing<T> = T extends object ? {
    [K in keyof T]: string extends K ? string[] : undefined extends T[K] ? string | undefined : string
  }[keyof T]
    : never
```

Comment: What makes something "strong" vs "loose" here?  Is it the [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures)?  Is it [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) in the property?  Is it something else?

Comment: Index signature!

Comment: @jcalz added update, pretty close

Comment: Also hey @jcalz, long time no see ^.^ thanks for all your help throughout the years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `string extends keyof T`:

```
type DoTheThing<T> =
  string extends keyof T ? string[] :
    T extends object ? {
      [K in keyof T]: undefined extends T[K] ? string | undefined : string
    } : never

type Strong = { cats: boolean }
type Loose = { [key: string]: any }

type A = DoTheThing<Strong> // { cats: string }
type B = DoTheThing<Loose> // string[]
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIg9gFQBYWQSwHYHMA8CB8UAvAFBRQDOwATpllBAB7AQYAmFUA1hCHAGZQEUAPyUadANoBdKAC4yQhs1YcocAEYArCAGNgoqAG9F5SQGkombrwFDpcqAFd2EfpghtlLdpwQXZMSpabCgAH2dXdwxPeXEQrEUAXziYgDcIahISUEgoAGUaOFCiYyhdAENgCkcNODgAGwgKjCgknPBoABl6imhSoyhJHhBHYLoHKBaQNuzc6ABBYlhEFHRsHELqYqxCAHo9ssrqsYlQ9vmoACFl+GRUJDocHrg+-cPx7BkSIA)

Comment: To @jcalz point this does not satisfy what I'm looking for because it's checking the undefined nature of T[K], and that's not what I'm looking for I need to tell if it has strongly typed keys.

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean. I copy-pasted the rest of your type and simply replaced `T extends {[key: string]: any}` with `string extends keyof T`, which checks if `T` has an index signature. I didn't touch the `undefined` part of it.

Comment: @ThomasReggi can you provide a [mre] of a use case this solution does not satisfy?

Comment: This does work!